# Using different tasks/conditions in Qualtrics

Tags: survey, qualtrics

I am currently working on a study (2x2x2 design) and I need to create 8 separate tasks for participants to do (between-subjects), and I was wondering if anyone knew if it's possible to create one survey file in Qualtrics that can redirect participants to any 1 of the 8 tasks, so that way I won't have to use 8 separate links to gather data.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in survey flow.  Just create your 8 tasks as different blocks.  Then go to the survey flow icon and insert a randomizer.  Drag your 8 tasks so they are indented under the randomizer and set the conditions of the randomizer (e.g. show 1 of 8 blocks or show 2 of 8 blocks....I think you want 1 of 8 blocks).  That's it!  Send everyone one link and Qualtrics will do the work of organizing who sees which block.